# Values are not set on the custom adapter list view

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I have a listview with a custom adapter. I am trying to set value to the listview using an adapter. But the values are not being set at run time, but it was working when implemented with a simpleadapter. My custom Adapter code is as follows.

```
   public class dataListAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    // HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList();

    public dataListAdapter(Context context,
            List<HashMap<String, String>> data, int resource,
            String[] from, int[] to) {

        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        this.data = data;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        if (null != data) {
            try {
                return data.get(arg0);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            final ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = mInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, parent, false);
        }

        Button vd = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.viewDetails);
        // Button gd = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.getDirections);
        Button ra = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.reqAppointment);
        final OnClickListener vdClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ListView listView = (ListView) parent;
                dataListAdapter adapter = (dataListAdapter) listView
                        .getAdapter();

                HashMap<String, String> item = (HashMap<String, String>) adapter
                        .getItem(position);

                // listView.getAdapter().get
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "vd clicked  Id  " + item,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };

        final OnClickListener gdClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "gdclicked  Id  ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        };

        final OnClickListener ravClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "req appclicked  Id  ",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        };

        vd.setOnClickListener(vdClickListener);
        // gd.setOnClickListener(gdClickListener);
        ra.setOnClickListener(ravClickListener);
        return row;
    }
}
```

This is how I set the values to the custom adapter.But the values are not set in the list view.

```
        String[] from = { "flag", "txt", "cur", "vd", "gd",
            "ra" };

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.flag, R.id.name, R.id.spec,
            R.id.vd, R.id.gd, R.id.ra};

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item

    adapter = new dataListAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList,
            R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

    // new CallToServer(adapter, aList).execute("");
    // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hm.put("txt", "Name  : " + "name");
    hm.put("cur", "spec: " + "spec");
    hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(0x7f020001));
    hm.put("but1", "");
    hm.put("but2", "");
    hm.put("but3", "");
    hm.put("ID", "100");
    aList.add(hm);
    System.out.println("Adapter object    " + adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    // Setting the adapter to the listView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnScrollListener(this);
    // setContentView(listView);
```

Can somebody guide me where I am going wrong, because the values set to the custom adapter are not shown in the listview.

I have tried adding onClickListener to the buttons and printed the item, and the values for the item are shown, like the name ,Id etc which are added are in the HashMap are shown, so its an issue in the rendering only ? Also the values are shown when I hard coded the values in the xml. Can somebody explain what can be the issue.

Comment: Post your getCount() code.

Comment: @jvrodrigues I haven't overridden that method, I have  only 3 overridden methods, they are
getView, getItem(int), and getItemId(int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the change needed was in the getView() method, I have added the following code in that, and it worked. This was the same code which I have used in the onClickListener()

```
TextView textView=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.specialization);
HashMap<String, String> item = (HashMap<String, String>) adapter.getItem(position);


 textView.setText(item.get("txt"));
```

I will be doing the same for other fields like images etc  . I think I can even use the viewholder  also.